# StackExchange RedisValue ToByteArray not Serializable

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

I am very new to `StackExchange.Redis` but I have been assigned a task to convert our Redis Cache to StackExchange.Redis. That said in one of our methods return the database values as a `byte[]`.

when I try: `var redisData = database.StringGet(key).ToByteArray();`

I get this error:

> Type 'StackExchange.Redis.RedisValue' in Assembly 'StackExchange.Redis, Version=1.1.608.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable

but when I do this: `var redisData = database.StringGet(key);` I get a value.

so my quesstion is: how can i convert `redisData` to a `byte[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the type that is returned by [`StringGet()`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/32807af6d64220f93c182fdc79d5969087f1d9d9/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/RedisDatabase.cs#L1446), which is `RedisValue`, you will see, that is it implicitly convertible to [`string`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/32807af6d64220f93c182fdc79d5969087f1d9d9/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/RedisValue.cs#L508) and [`byte[]`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/32807af6d64220f93c182fdc79d5969087f1d9d9/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/RedisValue.cs#L528). All you need to do to convert it is to simply use it as variable of type `byte[]` (let the implicit operator do the work) or cast it explicitly.

```
var redisData = (byte[])database.StringGet(key);
```

I assumed, that data you stored was a proper `byte[]` array. Otherwise, if you stored a `string`, eg. serialized object, you will get the byte representation of `string`.